# How to add fields to an existing XDP form

Tags: pdf, xsd, adobe, livecycle, xdp-pdf

This is my first time using LiveCycle. I have an existing XDP form to which I would like to add extra fields. In the screenshot below, I added the field on bottom right hand called `Test Field`. After creating this, I got a warning that the databinding value does not correspond to data connection. In the left pane window is what I believe the data connections are.

**Question**

How can I edit the existing dataconnections so that I can can add a dataconnection for the `testfield` that I've created?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Data View shows the existing data connection. You can edit it, delete or add new one.

You can bind data to the field by selecting the field and clicking binding tab in object palette(lower right corner on your screenshot). Click the trianlge beside the "Data Binding (Open, Save, Submit)". There you will have access to connected data.